# Identify exactly where memcmp fails

Tags: c, embedded, memcmp

Title is pretty self-explanatory, I am comparing two memory blocks that SHOULD be identical but I'm getting a failure. I have no idea where the test fails. Finding that out would help me debug the issue. So is there a way to find exactly where memcmp fails?

Comment: Write your own implementation of the function. It's trivial.

Comment: If you don't have access to the library source in your debugger so that you can step into it, simply write your own version of the function. Most embedded compilers do provide access to the library source though.

Comment: Please show how you are using `memcmp()`.

Comment: What failure? memcmp is around for decades, the chance that your implementation is incorrect is rather low.

Comment: Do you mean: "Where in the buffer position is a difference?" I don't think your title is so self-explanatory. Or does memcmp fail?

Comment: It is an XY problem.  You are asking about a solution you have invented to a problem you should be asking about.  Better to ask about the problem than the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
void *mymemcmp(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2, size_t num) {
    const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char*)ptr1;
    const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char*)ptr2;
    for(size_t index = 0; i<num; i++) {
        if(*s1 != *s2) return s1;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

It returns a pointer to the position of the first difference in the first argument. Then you can investigate it like this.

```
void *ao = mymecmp(a, b, n);
ptrdiff_t d = ao-(void*)a;
void *bo = d+(void*)b;
```

Now, `ao` and `bo` points to where the difference is.

Comment: A perfect use case for the downto operator: `while (num --> 0) { ... }`

Comment: @chqrlie muahahaha :D